# Laravel Nova Vue component not being rendered

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, laravel-nova

I have a laravel nova package where I define a custom vue component like this:

```
Nova.booting((Vue, router, store) => {
  Vue.component('my-component', require('./components/MyComponent').default);
});
```

I use it in a custom field like this:

```
Number::make('Custom field', function() {
   return view('my-package::custom_field')->render();
})->asHtml()
```

contents of `views/custom_field.blade.php`: `<my-component></my-component>`

the rendered custom field looks like this without vue component being rendered:

```
<my-component></my-component/>
```

So how can I define a global vue component that I can render inside a custom html nova field?

Comment: Same issue, did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @Notflip no :( but you could try asking in laravel discord

Comment: Any update here? Have the same problem